# Compiling android-ndk module with different STL than defined in Application.mk

Tags: android, c++, stl, android-ndk

I'm writing an android-ndk program that relies on `APP_STL := c++_static`

However, a particular module that builds a static library, doesn't compile unless `gnustl_static` is used instead.

Even if I manually added the necessary paths, e.g.:

```
-isystem $(NDK_ROOT)/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/$(NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION)/include
```

The compilation fails, because the `ndk-build` system prepends the stl-library paths it has been asked to use, in my case:

```
-I/opt/android-ndk-r9d/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/libcxx/include
```

---

Is there a way I can `tell ndk-build` to build a static library using a different stl? Or is this simply not possible, because linking a program with multiple implementations of the stl doesn't make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The NDK documentation states that you can't mix shared libraries compiled against different C++ runtimes. It's also true for static libraries, you shouldn't link to more than one C++ runtime either.

You have to adapt your projects to support only one these C++ runtimes (in your case, c++_static or gnustl_static).

Comment: Agreed. That what I ended up doing.